# Animate a span from width 0 to auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to create a website and have a menu that displays icons in the menu. When the menu button is clicked, the text will go next to each icon and push the menu out to the left so the text can fit.

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <a class="btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
        <div id="title-text">
            <a href="#section1" class="smoothScroll"><h3>Title</h3></a>
        </div>
            <!-- <div id="logo"> <a href="/"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo" /></a> </div> -->
            <nav id="nav" class="navigation" role="navigation">
                <ul class="newnav">
                    <li class="active" data-section="1"><i class="icon-home"></i> <span>Home</span></li>
                    <li data-section="2" class=""><i class="icon-user"></i> <span>About</li>
                    <li data-section="3" class=""><i class="icon-laptop"></i> <span>Projects</span> </li>
                    <li data-section="4" class=""><i class="icon-pencil"></i> <span>Social</span> </li>
                    <li data-section="5" class="last"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> <span>Contact</span> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav><!-- /nav -->
        </div><!-- /sidebar -->
```

At the moment, the spans expand to let the text in, it works fine but I would like it to be animated.

This is the majority of the code so far, although the live view isn't working.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztdgX/)

As you can see, when the top left button is clicked (.btn-navbar) the .expand CSS kicks in and changes the width from 0 to auto. I basically need the same thing but animated but cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: You can not animate to/from auto, but you can set a max-width: 0px and leave width: auto always (there are several answers about that solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate to `auto` using CSS or native Jquery (at least when I last checked)

There is a JS/JQ method though

[**http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/)

Comment: Don't copy-paste that code without reading the comments following it. The logic behind that method is pretty simple but quite difficult to implement. When making a clone of a node and setting it's width to `auto` it will be constrained by the clone's parent, not the original node's parent, so you'll have to be very careful.